# Using PowerMock with embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, unit-testing, tomcat, powermock, powermockito

I'm trying to mock a static method that is called by an embedded Tomcat instance. Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ExternalAPI.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*"})
public class TestExternalAPI
{

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(8080);
        tomcat.enableNaming();
        tomcat.addWebapp("/app", new File("src/test/webapp").getAbsolutePath());
        tomcat.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAPI() {
        mockStatic(ExternalAPI.class);
        when(ExternalAPI.getData()).thenReturn(new Data());

        //call Tomcat triggering the call to ExternalAPI.getData()
    }
}
```

With this configuration I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:849)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1060)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1783)
...
```

Now I thought that maybe I need to tell PowerMock to ignore the org.apache.* packages, but then I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:190)
    ... 54 more
```

I have also tried ignoring all org.* packages, which works, but then the ExternalAPI.getData() method is not mocked at all. I suppose this happens because nothing from the Tomcat instance is mocked in this case, since we are ignoring those org.apache.* packages.

Why do I get those exceptions and how should I configure PowerMock?

Edit: I'm using Tomcat 7. The tests run fine using the embedded Tomcat instance if PowerMock is not used.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're actually trying to accomplish here. Usually in a unit test, you would mock dependencies that your code relies on, and then call your code and ensures it uses the mocks properly. Unless you are writing *Tomcat*, I'm not sure I understand why you're embedding Tomcat instead of just mocking it. The scenario you describe at the very bottom is a perfect example of an *integration test*, and you should be doing those as well. But I don't get the unit test scenario here.

Comment: @dcsohl I want to test one whole flow for this web application. However, I want to mock the external calls triggered during that flow so no external system is needed when I run the tests. I'm trying to do this by deploying the app on an embedded Tomcat instance and then sending REST calls to it. This is all part of a legacy application that already has some tests that use this approach, so fully refactoring them is not really an option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set all required stuff when using tomcat in embedded mode like protocol , life cycle listeners if any , servlet classes , context parameters...

Sample code that worked for me...

```
    tomcat = new Tomcat();

    // Trigger loading of catalina.properties
    CatalinaProperties.getProperty("foo");

    File appBase = new File(getTemporaryDirectory(), "webapps");
    if (!appBase.exists() && !appBase.mkdir()) {
        Assert.fail("Unable to create appBase for test");
    }

    String protocol = getProtocol();

    Connector connector = new Connector(protocol);
    // Listen only on localhost
    connector.setAttribute("address",
    InetAddress.getByName("localhost").getHostAddress());
    // Use random free port
    connector.setPort(0);
    // Mainly set to reduce timeouts during async tests
    connector.setAttribute("connectionTimeout", "3000");
    tomcat.getService().addConnector(connector);
    tomcat.setConnector(connector);

    // Add AprLifecycleListener if we are using the Apr connector
    if (protocol.contains("Apr")) {
        StandardServer server = (StandardServer) tomcat.getServer();
        AprLifecycleListener listener = new AprLifecycleListener();
        listener.setSSLRandomSeed("/dev/urandom");
        server.addLifecycleListener(listener);
        connector.setAttribute("pollerThreadCount", Integer.valueOf(1));
    }

    File catalinaBase = getTemporaryDirectory();
    tomcat.setBaseDir(catalinaBase.getAbsolutePath());
    tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(appBase.getAbsolutePath());

    System.setProperty("org.apache.catalina.startup.EXIT_ON_INIT_FAILURE", "true");

    Context ctx = tomcat.addContext(getContext(), appBase.getAbsolutePath());
    ctx.setParentClassLoader(EmbeddedTomcatTestBase.class.getClassLoader());
    //Set execution independent of current thread context classloader (compatibility with exec:java mojo)

    Wrapper w = Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "ServletName", ServletClass.class.getName());
    w.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    w.addMapping("/ServletURI/*");
    w.addMapping("/ServletURI");
    w.addInitParameter("StatusPage", "/diagnostic/status.jsp");


    Wrapper w1 = Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "statusJSP", JspServlet.class.getName());
    w1.addMapping("/diagnostic/status.jsp");

    Wrapper w3 = Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "errorJSP", JspServlet.class.getName());
    w3.addMapping("/diagnostic/error.jsp");


    ctx.addParameter("EmbeddedMode", "true");

    ctx.addApplicationListener(ServletContextListnereClass.class.getName());

    ContextConfig contextConfig = new ContextConfig();
    ctx.addLifecycleListener(contextConfig);

    Tomcat.initWebappDefaults(ctx);
    tomcat.start();


   // initialize your engine / invoke any java methods of your interest here..
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but the embedded Tomcat is working fine for me. The problem appears only when I try to use PowerMock with it.